# Binary and memory?

Tags: performance, memory, binary

So today I was in my CS class and we were discussing binary. For example the number 26 110010. My professor said that the computer stores data in bytes which are 8 bits so 26 is really 000110010. Isn't that a huge waste of memory? I mean its only three bits but I'm assuming if it does this with everything under 8 bits it stacks up. Also what happens if a number takes 9 bits like 110010101 (405). What happens then?

Comment: Most modern machines are byte addressable with one byte taking 8 bits.  You cannot address less, if you want to pack more than one data item in a byte then you need bit tricks, like C bit fields.  If the data doesn't fit a byte then you'll need two bytes, a *short* in many languages.  Etcetera.  You can buy 64 billion bits for 60 bucks so not exactly something you worry about.

Answer (score 0):

It would waste far more memory to track the begin and end of each value so that you could accurately account for which bits were used in an arbitrary memory allocation scheme.

If you're working in an 8-bit type, you cannot store more than `11111111` (256 unsigned).  To go larger you have to start working with a 16 bit type and represent 405 as `0000000110010101`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually integers are often stored with 4 bytes, so 405 would be `00000000 00000000 00000001 10010101`. The thing is CPUs are very good at loading bytes of data at a time, not necessarily bits. It's really all about the instructions on the CPU. Plus, it's easier to find numbers in memory when you know how exactly many bytes each take up. If you want the 5th element, you can skip ahead 4*4 bytes and go right to the fifth rather than scanning all the bits to see how long each number is.